# ERROR: Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, web-config

**SOLVED**:the method `public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)` was erroneously returning null as the first item of the array.All good now.

I am trying to implement custom role and membership providers for my application but not having luck with role provider. In one of my controller's method, if I have `[Authorize]` directive it works fine but when I want to have role based authorization by adding `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` it gives an error saying *'Key cannot be null. Parameter name: key'*  .

I think there is something wrong with the entires in **web.config** file but cannot find what it is. The modified entries in web.config file look like

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="eLibrary.Models.CustomMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="AppDb" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="true" >
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="eLibrary.Models.CustomRoleProvider" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
```

It would be great if anyone can throw some lights on.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: post your upadate as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**:the method public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username) was erroneously returning null as the first item of the array.All good now.